# Enquiry about refusal of UK visa, is it an entry ban?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, working-visas, uk-visa, deception

I have a problem regarding a visit visa
I applied for a visit visa in Feb 2017 and it was refused and the refusal letter was not good.

My future application is at risk of being refused for up to 10 years. I am intending to apply for GMC registration within a year after which I will apply for a NHS job on skilled worker visa and I am afraid of visa refusal on future application, is there any help or guidance?

The officer claimed that the applied bank statement was not genuine.  After this refusal I headed to my bank in 2017 and they issued a proof [image]that my bank statement at that time was genuine, however I didn’t appeal on the decision at that time because some one advised me not to appeal as it will make the situation worse.

The problem is that I am planning to apply for a worker visa after I could finish the GMC registration in 2024.

Is this decision considered an entry ban and will it affect my application for a worker visa in the NHS after acceptance in a job offer?

Comment: If I were you I would consult an immigration lawyer before applying https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-9-grounds-for-refusal

Comment: It's not a ban; it's a warning that if your next application is refused for misrepresentation then you will most likely receive an entry ban.  An immigration lawyer will be much more confident navigating this than you will.  For example they will be more likely to know whether it's possible to find out what "checks" the Home Office made and why they showed that the bank statement was false (it would not be surprising if the HO reached this conclusion through incompetence).  They would also know how useful it would be to you to pursue that vs. just applying again now.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the situation is complex and warrants informed advice from a qualified immigration lawyer.

Comment: Also bear in mind *Previous breach of immigration laws* as potential grounds for future refusals.